# How to prevent JS Date from magically adding a non-existent day and month?

Tags: javascript, regex, date, momentjs, date-conversion

I'm using moment.js and the JavaScript Date constructor to automatically parse a load of dates, the format of which could be anything.

Consider the following code:

```
var dateString = "June 2013";
var dateObj    = new Date(dateString);
console.log(dateObj); // Sat Jun 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)
```

We can see that the behaviour is to set the day to the 1st (similarly with the month if none is specified).

I understand this behaviour, but when I query the `Date` object and ask for the day, it will return me a day when none was originally specified.

Other than doing a bunch of regex processing on the original string, is there any way around this?

Thanks!

Comment: *'...when I query the date object and ask for the day'* - and what should be returned in the 'June 2013' case?

Comment: Well I guess it will always return 1, so there's nothing I can do about that - what I'm asking is if there's a way to detect that it should in fact be 0

Comment: You can create your own wrapper for Date objects (wrapper, not extension) with custom flags for non-complete dates.

Answer (score 0):

> when I query the Date object and ask for the day, it will return me a day when none was originally specified.

Use a variable to store the string, then use `defineProperty` on those instances to override the `getDate` callback:

```js
    var dateString = "June 2013";
    var foo = new Date(dateString);

    if (dateString.match(/\s[0-31]\s/) === null)
      {
      Object.defineProperty(foo, 'getDate', {value: function(){return null} });
      }
    console.log(foo.getDate() );
```

**References**

- [Object.defineProperty() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)
- [Date.prototype.getDate() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate)